# How to run a C program when it has multiple files?

Tags: c, makefile

In a program, I have a list.c file, list.h file and run.c file. In the run.c file, the code contains my main program and also "#include list.h". In my list.h file, my functions are just void and being defined. Finally, in my list.c file, I include list.h again and I have the meaning and code of what each function is going to do. I made a makefile that looks like so:

```
SOURCES = run.c list.c
OBJECTS= run.o list.o
HEADERS = list.h
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -g -Wall

lab1: $(OBJECTS)
(tab)    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o lab1

clean:
(tab)    rm -fR *o lab1
```

There is nothing wrong in any of my code because it is already finished and I am just copying code. However, I am unsure how to use the makefile to run these multiple files. I am only familiar with runner files after compiling with gcc and using "./". Is there something wrong with my makefile or is there a step for compiling these files in a different way?

Thank you for any help

Comment: you need a target for the `$(OBJECTS)` that will utilize `SOURCES`. Typically, your `lab1` target is the final executable, and the command there should be for linking, ie, `$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS)...`. You need a target and corresponding command that describes how to build those objects, ie, `$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(SOURCES) ...`. This may help: http://mrbook.org/blog/tutorials/make/

Comment: @yano After reading the link, I compiled it the way it said to and it gave me all the files that are in my makefile. I'm assuming it compiled? How would I run these multiple files to test it?

Comment: The `- lab1` at the end of compile command doesn't seem right. Did you mean `-o lab1` ?

Comment: @user3386109 However, I still can't seem to run my current code

Comment: Ok, if the compile was successful, you should have a file called *"lab1"*. To run it, type `./lab1` at the command prompt. Assuming that the current working directory is the directory that has "lab1" in it.

Comment: I would change the *clean* command to `rm -f *.o lab1`. The command that you have is a little bit dangerous. It will recursively delete any directory that ends with an `o`.

Comment: The other comments and answers have said it. If everything compiled you should have a `lab1` executable. Do `ls -l` and you should see the `x` executable flag for `lab1`, and then just `./lab1` to run it. If that doesn't exist something is wrong. Running `make -d` will output more detailed information about what `make` is doing, and may offer clues if there's a problem.

Comment: Just FYI: although not recommended, it is possible to feed all the `.c` files to a single call to the compiler: `$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(SOURCES) -o lab1`.

Answer (score 5):

The given makefile is working and generates an executable `lab1` file. However, the `.o` files depend on the `list.h` file, and this dependency is not captured.

You should specify targets to build the .o files, as follows:

```
SOURCES = run.c list.c
OBJECTS= run.o list.o
HEADERS = list.h
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -g -Wall

lab1: $(OBJECTS)
(tab)    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o lab1

%.o: %.c $(HEADERS)
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -fR *o lab1
```

---

**Word of caution:** With this makefile, if the list of `HEADERS` grows, a change in *any* of the headers will warrant a rebuild of *all* `.o` files.

For example, imagine we also have `buf.c` which uses `buf.h`. Now `HEADERS = list.h buf.h`. If we change `buf.h`, our makefile would rebuild both `list.o` and `buf.o`, even though a `buf.o` rebuild would suffice.

To remedy this, we could use a more verbose makefile which identifies the specific header prerequisites for each `.o` file with rules such as the following:

```
list.o: list.c list.h
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

buf.o: buf.c buf.h
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Comment: You don't need to specify each `.o` separately, since you can generalise that to a rule for `.c.o`. And you don't even need to do that, because a POSIX-compliant `make` utility implements the `.c.o` rule by default. All you need is to specify `$OBJECTS`, AFAIK.

Comment: @Rhymoid Sounds like the original question's makefile was working just fine due to the implicit `.c.o` rule you mentioned. I agree that my two .c -> .o rules could be replaced by a single `%.o: %.c $(HEADERS)` rule. I have edited my answer. However, a suffix rule such as `.c.o` cannot have prerequisite rules such as `$(HEADERS)` according to https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Suffix-Rules.html. Same goes for implicit rules according to https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Using-Implicit.html. It's probably better to capture this prerequisite than to ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1: Simply list each .c file separately as input and compile once

```
gcc list.c run.c -o lab1
```

Solution 2: Compile each .c file separately

```
gcc -c list.c
gcc -c run.c
gcc -o lab1 list.o run.o
```

Your project is small and simple enough that a fully generalized makefile is overkill:

```
SOURCES = run.c list.c
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -g -Wall

all:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(SOURCES) -o lab1

clean:
    rm -fR *o lab1
```

The `all:` is a default target that executes when you simply type `make` with no arguments.

Comment: The trouble with this is — two-fold (one immediate problem, one incipient problem).  The immediate problem is that it will recompile everything every time you run `make` or `make all` because `all` is never created so the command will be executed.  The incipient problem is that if you fix the immediate proble with `all: lab1` and then `lab1:` plus the `CC` command,  then it won't recompile the program if there are changes to the header — and probably not to the source files either.  You should link the object files, and you should specify that the object files depend on the header.

Comment: For a project the size of this one, it probably isn't much quicker to do the separate compilations.  For larger scale projects, it is much more important.

Comment: Hence the statement  "Your project is small and simple enough". The submitter is trying to finish his homework, not create a scalable build infrastructure. My experience is that this kind of thing is a stumbling block to students much more than a help (the fact that this assignment is the first lab is particularly telling), and that people will naturally learn the more advanced techniques when it becomes necessary. Trying to teach students how to build proper makefiles for trivial projects is destined for failure. Just my opinion though- there's plenty of info here to see both sides.

Answer (score 0):

After compiling, it did end up making a lab1 file that I could run and everything worked. My makefile ended up working fine, I was just completely oblivious to the fact that it was making a file called lab1. I did change my makefile to the above options and that also worked. Thank you